# When to use present perfect and adjective? Especially for emotions

Tags: prepositions

Is this sentence is correct?

1. I have been tired of you.

Also please tell me when to use present perfect tense for emotions I mean am I still tired? If yes then why not say I'm tired of you.
Like in this sentence 
2. I have been worried about you.
3. I have been worrying about you.
What do they mean differently.

Comment: You can use the present perfect for a feeling you still have now, if you want to say when it started, e.g. *I have been bored of you ever since we went to Sicily* (which means that the speaker is still bored). Otherwise use the present tense (*I'm bored of you*). There is not much difference between 2 and 3 in many contexts, but in some there is. For example, in *I have been worried about you at times, but I think you'll pull through*, you couldn't really use *worrying* instead. It is better to think of use cases rather than tenses - otherwise it gets very confusing.

Comment: Could you please explain 'cases rather than tenses' further.

Comment: Could you please explain 'cases rather than tenses' further. I mean for emotions, behavior, present tense and perfect tense both look fine. Another example 4. You are disrespectful towards me. 5. You have been disrespectful towards me. They both look fine to me

Comment: They are both fine, but they mean different things. As for 'use cases' rather than 'tenses', each tense has a number of different use cases i.e. can be used in different situations with different meanings. For example the present perfect can be used to refer to something that has already been decided and is expected to take place in the future (*I am moving to France in two years' time*) but can also be used to refer to something that is happening right now. It's more helpful to think of those as being two separate things than to look for a more general rule that explains both.

Comment: You said that they mean different. What do the they mean different? Please explain I think number 4 is behavior at that particular moment and 5 is behavior at all times. Am I right?